Establishing hls on another website player
We are using nginx and rtmp to restream from another server rtmp , we can open it on vlc but its not possible to fetch data on browser when we upload on another domain it shows cors error, we also added header to our config files but it still shows the error
this is our nginx.conf details ;
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

        keepalive_timeout  65;  gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
#        chunk_size 4096;
#        allow publish 127.0.0.1;
#        allow publish 185.126.201.73;
#        allow publish 185.126.201.76;
        allow publish all;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            hls on;
            hls_path /var/www/html/stream/hls;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            dash on;
            dash_path /var/www/html/stream/dash;

        }
    }
}



and this is our ; /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rtmp
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    # rtmp stat
    location /stat {
        rtmp_stat all;
        rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    }
    location /stat.xsl {
        root /var/www/html/rtmp;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    # rtmp control
    location /control {
        rtmp_control all;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    # HLS live streaming
    location /hls {
        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }
        root /var/www/html/stream/hls;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';

            add_header Content-Length 0;
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            return 204;
        }
    }

    # DASH live streaming
    location /dash {
        types {
            application/dash+xml mpd;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }
        root /var/www/html/stream/dash;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            return 204;
        }
    }
}
server {
    listen 8088;

    location / {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        root /var/www/html/stream;
    }
}


